# jquery: How to select the checkbox that has an array value in its attribute name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-1.9, prop

How can I use jquery to select the checkbox that has **an array value** in its attribute name?

html,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="1"/>
```

My attempt that does not work,

```
$('input:checkbox[name=delete]',container).not('input:checkbox[disabled=disabled]').prop('checked', true);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('input:checkbox[name^=delete]',container)
```

or this:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="delete[]"]',container)
```

or this:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=delete\\[\\]]',container)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you're checking an attribute value, you can just wrap the value in double quotes (anything within the quotes is treated literally):

```
$('input:checkbox[name="delete[]"]')
```

Or more generally, escape the special characters:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=delete\\[\\]]');
```

The method for escaping, and the list of special characters, is covered at the start of the documentation for [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).